# How do placeholders work in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code -

```
object TextTransformer {
    def transform (strings: String*)= {
        println(strings.map(x => x.toLowerCase()))
        println(strings.map(_.toUpperCase()))
    }
}
```

In the lower case version, we are using anonymous function and passing an argument `x` to it, which makes sense.

What is the magic behind `toUpperCase` function ? What if a variable was already defined as `_`? How `map` able to work with the return value of `_.toUpperCase()` instead of using the `_.toUpperCase` as the iteratee?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. These two line are the same. Using placeholder is syntax sugar for cases when function's parameter are used just once in function's body.

Comment: But why am I not passing it like `_.toUpperCase` rather than `_.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @Tushar you're able to use both variants and there is no difference between them in this case.

Comment: Isn't that confusing?

Comment: @Tushar I think I'm not understand you correctly. Why does ability of using two variants confuse you?

Comment: it looks like  in one case a function is being passed as a parameter, in the second case, it looks like the return value of the called function is being passed, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tushar no, in both cases you pass function which returns uppercased version of its argument.

Comment: @Tushar `map` requires a function here, so the parameter can't just be a `String`, and the compiler knows it. There are a few ways to pass functions as parameters in Scala: using `x =>` is more general, `_` is a special case. You can also use both parens `map(f(_))` or braces `map { f(_) }`. Scala allows you to leave off empty parameter lists, as in `_.toUpperCase`, but that's independent of passing a function as a parameter.